# Apache Camel's PropertyInject using Guice Injector

Tags: apache-camel, guice

Does camel's  @PropertyInject work with Guice. I tried using this with Guice the value is never set. But the same code works when Spring is used as DI.  After looking at the code, org.apache.camel.guice.impl.GuiceInjector does not support CamelBeanPostProcessor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think so as there is not many users of camel-guice and its not a primary focus. We love contributions, so you are welcome to dive into the code and see what it takes to add support for those annotations. Maybe take a look at camel-cdi which supports them, and its a bit similar concept as guice.